# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in

Tags: php, apache, dll, phpmyadmin, settings

Hi see this Question all over the place. But the answers did not solve my issue. I am still getting the same problem with:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\inetpub\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177

I have tried everything and none of it is working for me. I have the `php_mbstring.dll` enabled:

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      

;Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  

;Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

I got my Apache HTTP Server 2.2 set up with the `php5apache2_2.dll`. I even tried making a copy of `php.ini` to `config.ini` become some one said that worked for them.

Comment: ;extension=php_ldap.dll extension=php_mbstring.dll extension=php_exif.dll all appears on the same and within a comment. put extension=php_mbstring.dll on a separate line and restart your apache.

Comment: just listing a .dll in .ini doesn't mean it was actually loaded. you need to check `php_info()` to see if the MB module is actual listed.

Comment: OK Did this and still did not help. I have checked the php info but I do not see any thing that talks about the extensions where should they be listed?????

Answer (score 0):

I got past the error by placing a copy of php.ini in C:/windows. Is there any way to change where it looks for that file and others???
Also now have a full blank page when I try to open phpMyAdmin. and one other page that seem to need databases. I dont even know if I have a database 
HELP